# Transformation in regression with no regressors and equi-correlated disturbances

Tags: least-squares

I'm working on a problem in which we consider a simple regression with no regressors and equi-correlated disturbances. So we have

$y_i = \alpha + \varepsilon_i$

where $E[\varepsilon_i, \varepsilon_j] = 0$

and $Cov[\varepsilon_i, \varepsilon_j]=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\rho \sigma^2 & i\neq j\\ 
\sigma^2 & i=j
\end{matrix}\right.$

The above model can be rewritten as $y = \alpha\iota_n + u$

Since $\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$ we can say $\hat\alpha_{OLS}=(\iota_n'\iota_n)^{-1}\iota_n'y$. In Baltagi (2010) I found that $\hat\alpha_{OLS}=(\iota_n'\iota_n)^{-1}\iota_n'y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{y_i}{n}=\bar{y}$. How is this last transformation derived? I fail to understand how the sum comes into play here as well as the n.

Further, it is stated that

$\Psi = E[\varepsilon\varepsilon']=\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2 & \rho\sigma^2 & {...} &\rho\sigma^2 \\ 
\rho\sigma^2 &\sigma^2  & {...} & \rho\sigma^2\\ 
{...} &  {...}  & {...} &{...}\\ 
\rho\sigma^2 &{...}  &{...}  &\sigma^2 
\end{pmatrix}= \sigma^2(1-\rho)I+\rho\sigma^2\iota\iota'$.

The matrix makes sense to me but here I also fail to understand the last step how one derives the expression

$\sigma^2(1-\rho)I+\rho\sigma^2\iota\iota'$ from the matrix. Maybe someone can explain, help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand both if you consider that $\iota_n$ is a vector of $1$s of dimension $(n \times 1)$.

In the formula for $\alpha_{OLS}$ the $(\iota_n' \iota_n)$ is the inner product of two vectors of $1$s of dimension $(1 \times n)$ and $(n \times 1)$, since the first one is transposed, which is the sum of the products of their $n$ elements: $\underbrace{1*1+1*1+...1*1}_{n \text{ times}} = n$. Since it is taking the inverse you get the $n$ in the denominator.

The second part is again the inner product between the vector of $1$s of dimension $(1 \times n)$ and the vector $y$ of dimension $(n \times 1)$, hence $\iota_n y = \sum_{i=1}^n 1*y_i = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$.

Regarding the matrix $\Psi$, $\sigma^2(1-\rho)I$ is a diagonal $(n \times n)$ matrix with  $\sigma^2(1-\rho)$ in the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere. The second part is a $(n \times n)$ matrix where every element is $\rho \sigma^2$, since $\iota \iota'$ is a matrix of $1$s.

Comment: Now I understand, thanks a lot!